# Get PID of a backgrouded shell command in C

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I want to execute a Linux command from in a C program and get its PID, as well as its output.

For example in `executeShellCommand()`  function below, how can I access the PID of the process which is started?

### commandTest.cpp

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

// execute a shell command and return its output
std::string executeShellCommand(const char* cmd) 
{
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!";
    try {
        while (!std::feof(pipe)) {
            if (std::fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pipe))
                result += buffer;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "executeShellCommand : "
              << executeShellCommand(argv[1]) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ 1 ]]
do
   sleep 1
done
```

Run with:

```sh
./commandTest "./test.sh & echo $!"
```

Comment: Okay. What have you done so far? What isn't working?

Comment: `man 3 posix_spawn`

Comment: you can echo from shell ID of last backgrounded process. `echo $!;` or ID of current process `echo $$;`

Comment: You mentioned `popen()` doesn't work, what error you got?. Getting a pid of process can be done in many ways in POSIX. Just have a look at this http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html

Comment: @Lethal - `getpid()` isn't what's required here - for the id of a child, we need to save the result of `fork()`.  That means reimplementing enough of `popen` to do that, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this:

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctime>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional> //for std::hash
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// execute a shell command and return its output
string executeShellCommand(const char* cmd) 
{
    char buffer[128];
    string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) throw runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    try {
        while (!feof(pipe)) {
            if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                result += buffer;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }
    pclose(pipe);

// remove new line character from result string
int pos;
while((pos=result.find('\n')) != string::npos)
                    result.erase(pos);
    return result;
}

int executeShellCommandPid(const char* cmd) 
{
string localCommand(cmd);

// make a file name using the input command and the current time
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer[80];    
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime); 
strftime(buffer,sizeof(buffer),"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S",timeinfo);
string currentTime(buffer); 
hash<string> hasher;
    string fileName = to_string(hasher(localCommand+currentTime)); 

localCommand = localCommand + " & echo $! | grep -w -o -E '[0-9]*'>" + fileName + ".pid";
system(localCommand.c_str());
localCommand = "cat " + fileName + ".pid";
int pid = stoi(executeShellCommand(localCommand.c_str()));
localCommand = "rm -rf " + fileName + ".pid";
system(localCommand.c_str());
return pid;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// variable definitions
string ARG_COM = argv[1];

cout << "system : " << system(ARG_COM.c_str()) << endl;
//cout << "executeShellCommand : " << executeShellCommand(ARG_COM.c_str()) << endl;
//cout << "executeShellCommandPid : " << executeShellCommandPid(ARG_COM.c_str()) << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the command echo `$!`, which contains the PID of the most recent background process created, then read it.

```
FILE *p = popen("some command & echo $!");
int pid;
fscanf(p, "%d", &pid);
pclose(p);
```